# Can't use a model method in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a ticket booking app as my sample project using Ruby on Rails 4.1. Three are three models - Events, Tickets and Bookings. Events have many tickets and bookings. Tickets have many bookings and they belong to events. Bookings belongs to events and tickets.

The tickets controller looks like:

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @tickets = @event.tickets.all
end

def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @ticket = @event.tickets.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @ticket = Ticket.new
end

def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @ticket = @event.tickets.create(ticket_params)
    if @ticket.save
        redirect_to [@event, @ticket]
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @ticket= @event.tickets.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @ticket = @event.tickets.find(params[:id])

    if @ticket.update(ticket_params)
        redirect_to [@event, @ticket]
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @ticket = @event.tickets.find(params[:id])
    @ticket.destroy
    redirect_to event_tickets_path
end


private

def ticket_params
    params.require(:ticket).permit(:ticket_name, :booking_start_date, :booking_end_date, :ticket_price, :ticket_quantity, :minimum_quantity, :maximum_quantity, :terms_conditions, :more_information)
end
```

end

The ticket model looks like this

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :event
 has_many :bookings

 def maximum_tickets_allowed
    max = ticket.maximum_quantity.to_i
    self.maximum_quantity = (1..max).to_a
 end

   end
```

The Tickets show file looks like:

```
<h2>Tickets</h2>

<p><%= @ticket.ticket_name %></p>
<p><%= @ticket.booking_start_date %></p>
<p><%= @ticket.booking_end_date %></p>
<p><%= @ticket.maximum_tickets_allowed %></p>
```

`maxium_quantity` is the maximum number of tickets a person can book and I'm trying here to convert it to an array to be used in `collection_select`.

Now, if I use `<%= @ticket.maximum_tickets_allowed %>` I get the `undefined method`maximum_tickets_allowed'`error. I tried using`self.maximum_tickets_allowed` but it doesn't work. Where am I going wrong?

**Full Stack Trace of the error:**

```
activemodel (4.1.1) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in `method_missing'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:206:in `method_missing'
app/views/tickets/show.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_tickets_show_html_erb__2112154808966627486_70166705061960'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:62:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:99:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:82:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/Users/mohan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/Users/mohan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/mohan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/mohan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: post your controller action and view please.

Comment: Also post your full error stacktrace please

Comment: Also i think `ticket` is undefined. If you want the `maximum_quantity` attribute you can use call it on `self.maximum_quantity` or just `maximum_quantity`

Comment: @DickieBoy I have updated the question with controller and view files

Comment: You shouldn't be getting undefined method. Post the full stack trace

Comment: @DickieBoy I tried replacing ticket.maximum_quantity with self.maximum_quantity and maximum_quantity. Same error occurs.

Comment: @DickieBoy Updated the question with the stack trace.

Comment: @Pavan Updated the question with the stack trace.

Comment: What is the database schema for this model? Maybe the attribute name is just incorrect, something like max_quantity, for instance.

Comment: @GregBurghardt It's maximum_quantity. I did an experiment in the meantime. Replaced the model method code with a simple maximum_quantity.to_i * minimum_quantity.to_i. Still got the same error!

Comment: Hm. You are using @event.tickets.find, and i wonder if it is returning nil instead of throwing an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error like Ticket.find would do?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I'm sorry, I didn't get you.

Comment: @GregBurghardt In the view rest of the parameters show up fine if I remove @ticket.maximum_tickets_allowed. There is totally no response for any model method whatsoever from the ticket model. As I mentioned earlier, simple multiplication results aren't even shown and I get the same undefined method `maximum_tickets_allowed' error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to think about.

From the comments, it sounds like maybe the `@ticket` variable is nil? I'm not sure if `@event.tickets.find(params[:id])` will throw an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFoundError` like `Ticket.find` will. The way you get data for your controllers is kind of butting heads with the Rails way. There is a one to many relationship between Ticket and Event. There is no need to pass an `event_id` and `id` to the `TicketsController#show` method. Just pass the ticket Id:

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @ticket = Ticket.find params[:id]
    @event = @ticket.event
  end

end
```

Using `Ticket.find` will raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFoundError` if the ticket doesn't exist. If I remember correctly, the default controller error handling in Rails should trap that specific exception and render a 404 Not Found page, so after `Ticket.find` you are assured to have a Ticket object.

Next, if you still need an `@event` instance variable, use the ActiveRecord relations to get it via `@ticket.event`.

Now the model itself would need the following code:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :bookings

  def maximum_tickets_allowed
    (1..self.maximum_quantity).to_a
  end
end
```

The `maximum_tickets_allowed` method should just return an array. I'm also wondering if the method call as the end value of the Range is tripping up the Ruby interpreter. You could try instantiating a Range object directly:

```
  def maximum_tickets_allowed
    Range.new(1, maximum_quantity).to_a
  end
```

The view remains unchanged:

```
<h2>Tickets</h2>

<p><%= @ticket.ticket_name %></p>
<p><%= @ticket.booking_start_date %></p>
<p><%= @ticket.booking_end_date %></p>
<p><%= @ticket.maximum_tickets_allowed %></p>
```

**Edit #1:** As the comments above mention, make sure you've run all the Active Record migrations in case the maximum_quantity column in the database has been added recently, otherwise that method will not be auto generated by ActiveRecord when the Rails app boots up.

**Edit #2:** In your `show` method, you are finding the Event, then all tickets and grabbing only one of the tickets available to the event. That's not as efficient as grabbing the ticket, since you've got the id, and then grabbing the event from the ticket object.

I didn't find any documentation on the `find` method of an ActiveRecord collection, so I'm not able to validate its behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. After multiple tries, this method started working again. Your suggestion from yesterday worked fine today. I started Rails server every single time and even tried renaming the method multiple times. However, it started working all of a sudden. Could browser cache be a reason(but the change in method names were shown after every page load)?

Comment: If the `TicketsController#show` page was cached by the browser, it probably was showing the cached version of that page each time instead of actually making an HTTP request to the server. What are the cache headers sent back to the browser?

Comment: I don't know the cache headers. But, I did try renaming the method multiple times - max_charge, max_collect etc. and I remember noticing that the method name in the error page changing with each page load (most of the times I looked at them, but I could have missed).

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking `ticket.maximum_quanitity` inside the method, should it not just be `maximum_quantity` since you're using a ticket instance method?

Comment: Just returning `(1..maximum_quantity.to_i).to_a` should be sufficient.

Comment: @agmcleod I fixed that and still no change.

Comment: @GregBurghardt tried that now and it still isn't budging.

Comment: Hmm, did you run the migrations? Can sometimes run into this issue on accessing a column if `rake db:migrate` isn't run yet. Can also test in rails console to see what works. `Ticket.new.maximum_quanitity` for example.